# lognormal distribution $z = \frac xy$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have a problem that says

> The random variable $Y$ has lognormal distribution with $u = 2$ and $o = 0.4$. $z = \frac xy$. *(recall log properties)*
>
> Find $P(Z\leq 6)$.

The solution begins saying $\ln Z = \ln X-\ln Y$ so $Z$ is lognormal with $u = 3-2 = 1$ and $o = \sqrt{(0.5)^2 + (0.4)^2} = \sqrt{0.41}$.

$P(Z\leq 6) = P\left(Z \leq \frac{\ln6 - 1}{\sqrt{0.41}}\right) = F(1.24) = 0.8925$

This is confusing to me, I don't know how they got $u = 3-2 = 1$ and $o = \sqrt{(0.5)^2 + (0.4)^2}$. I have been analyzing the book and my notes in this section, I tried applying the main formula for $Y\sim \log(u,o^2)$, and I thought I'd use the given $2$ and $0.4$ for $u$ and $o$ in final $P(Z\leq 6)$ equation.

I also thought it might be the $X-Y\sim N(ux-uy,o^2x + o^y)$ , but then I have no idea why hes using $ux = 3$ and $o^x = 0.5$.

Can someone please explain the process of how they found the $u = 1$ and $o = \sqrt{0.41}$ steps?

Comment: Is $X$ of lognormal? What do we know about $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some information, but I can infer it from the work that you have.

> Suppose $X$ is lognormal with $\mu = 3$ and $\sigma = 0.5$, and $Y$ is
>   lognormal with $\mu = 2$ and $\sigma = 0.4$, and $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Find the distribution of
>   $Z = \dfrac{X}{Y}$.

Recall that if $X^{\prime}$ is **normally distributed** with $(\mu, \sigma)$, then $X = e^{X^{\prime}}$ has a lognormal distribution with $(\mu, \sigma)$.

It follows that - taking the natural logarithm of both sides - that $\ln(X)  = \ln(e^{X^{\prime}}) = X^{\prime}$. Since $X^{\prime}$ is normally distributed with $(\mu, \sigma)$, $\ln(X)$ is also normally distributed with $(\mu, \sigma)$ if $X$ has a lognormal distribution with $(\mu, \sigma)$.

Hence, taking the natural logarithm of both sides of $Z$ gives
$$\ln(Z) = \ln\left(\dfrac{X}{Y}\right) = \ln(X)-\ln(Y)\text{.}$$
Since $X$ is lognormal with $\mu = 3$ and $\sigma = 0.5$, $\ln(X)$ is normally distributed with $\mu = 3$ and $\sigma = 0.5$. Since $Y$ is lognormal with $\mu = 2$ and $\sigma = 0.4$, $\ln(Y)$ is normally distributed with $\mu = 2$ and $\sigma = 0.4$.

Hence, $\ln(Z) = \ln(X) - \ln(Y)$ is a difference of normal distributions, which is also normally distributed with 
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\ln(Z)] &= \mathbb{E}[\ln(X)-\ln(Y)] = \mathbb{E}[\ln(X)] - \mathbb{E}[\ln(Y)] = 3 - 2 = 1 \\
\text{Var}[\ln(Z)] &=  \text{Var}[\ln(X)-\ln(Y)] \\
&= \text{Var}[\ln(X)] + \text{Var}[\ln(Y)] \quad \text{(assuming independence)}\\
&= 0.5^2 + 0.4^2 
\end{align*}$$
hence $\ln(Z)$ is normal with $(\mu = 1, \sigma = \sqrt{\text{Var}[\ln(Z)]} = \sqrt{0.5^2 + 0.4^2})$. Thus, $e^{\ln(Z)} = Z$ is lognormal with the same $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: oh wow i forgot that information was at the top of the paper. no wonder i'm so confused. haha i've been up for a while.. thanks